# In Firebase, how to update a child of all nodes from the previous level?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

It is my first time structuring data in a firebase database.

I understood that I should optimize for reading operations, and denormalize.

I have a list of projects, and a list of users. Also, each user has a list of projects associated with it.

I have no trouble reading and displaying data. But, if **I have to edit the name of a specific project**, I don't know how to do it correctly.

Having the key of that project I can update using `projects/key/name`, but I also have to update the name in the projects associated with each user. I tried using `users/*/key` but nothing happened.

I am using firebase with javascript in a basic web application.

[image]

Initially I had a `true` value for all projects within the `users` node (instead of the name). With this approach I just have to update in the  `projects` node, but I have to perform a multiple reading operations.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need two indexes for this:

1. to find the projects for a user (you already have this)
2. to find the users for a project

I'd store the two lookup lists as top-level lists:

```
users
  $uid
    admin: true
projects
  $projectid
    name: "Name of project"
    description: "Description of project"
userProjects
  $uid
    $projectid: "Name of project"
projectUsers
  $projectid
    $uid: true
```

With this structure you can look up everything that you need without having to fire an expensive query.

When you update the project name, you'll just load the project's users and then iterate over this. If you feel fancy, you can even use a multi-location `update()` to update them all in one go. See this blog post for more in that: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/client-side-fan-out-for-data-consistency_73.html